# checkbox form ouput is not as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, ruby-2.0

I'm having problems creating a checkbox form in rails 4. There are two issues, the first is that as well as next to each checkbox, at the end of the form all of the ids and names of the categories are printed out with additional ugly formatting in one big list. The second issue is that when I use

```
id: dom_id(category)
```

to assign unique ids to each field, all the options become pre-selected.

```
 <div class="field"> 
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[category_ids][]", nil %>
    <%= UserCategory.all.each do |category| %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'user[category_ids][]', category.id, , id:  dom_id(category) %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(category), category.name %><br>
    <% end %> 
  </div>
```

Ugly formatting at end of form:

```
[#<Category id: 1, name: "school">, #<Category id: 2, name: "college">, #<Category id: 3, name: "university">, #<Category id: 4, name: "post-graduation">, #<Category id: 5, name: "doctorate">, #<Category id: 6, name: "master">, #<Category id: 7, name: "bachelor">, #<Category id: 8, name: "grad">, #<Category id: 9, name: "middle-school">, #<Category id: 10, name: "junior-school">, #<Category id: 11, name: "senior-school">]
```

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate the `=` from the `<%` at the start of the `UserCategory` loop. It should be:

```
<% UserCategory.all.each do |category| %>
```

For your second problem, you need to add `false` to the `check_box_tag` call:

```
<%= check_box_tag 'user[category_ids][]', category.id, false, id:  dom_id(category) %>
```

Comment: thanks! that solved the problem of the ugly formatted list at the end. When do we use <%= as opposed to <% ? It seems fairly arbitrary to me...

Comment: Use `<%=` when you want to output the result of the code in between the `<%..%>`. Use the `<%` when you only want the code to execute - not output to the page. More often than not, loops themselves only use `<%`.

Comment: @chris I think I found your second issue with my edit above